# Referencing Equation in a list inline mode

Tags: math-mode, cross-referencing, lists, enumerate

I have been using align for referencing equations, however now in a list, using inline math mode and trying to reference an equation, there is text on the line hence why i don't want to begin an equation however do want it to uphold referencing numbers, MWE as follows

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\roman{enumii}}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{\textbullet~}\begin{enumerate}[i.]

\begindocument

\begin{enumerate}[i.]
\item{ y=f(x), \text{ where } a,b \in \R \text{ are fixed} \text{,}\label$}
\item{$ F(x,y)=0, \text{ } a_1 \leq x \leq a_2,\text{ }b_1 \leq y \leq b_2 \text{ where, } a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2 \in \R \text{,}$}
\item{$
  \left\{\begin{array}{cll}
    x=g(t)\\
    y=h(t)
  \end{array}\right. \text{, where }c_1<t< c_2 \text{ and } c_1,c_2 \in \R
  \text{.}$}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{equation}
  C:
  \left\{\begin{array}{cll}
    x=\cos(t) \\
    y=\sin(t)
  \end{array}\right. \text{, where } u \in \Big[ - \frac {\pi}{4},\frac {\pi}{4} \Big]
  \text{.}
 \end{equation}

 \end document
```

Comment: `\item` does not use `{...}` -- it has an optional argument however, `\label$` is pretty useless and wrong, of course. Please correct the 'document'

Comment: `\R` is no valid command. You mean `\mathbb{R}` most likely, i.e. the usual blackboard letter for indicating the set of real numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A proposition with `enumerate` package replaced by `enumitem` and using its `label` and `ref` options.

I also fixed *some* of the typos and wrong usages.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\roman*.)}, ref={\roman*.)}]
\item $y=f(x), \text{ where } a,b \in \mathbb{R} \text{ are fixed},\label{foo}$
\item $ F(x,y)=0, \text{ } a_1 \leq x \leq a_2,\text{ }b_1 \leq y \leq b_2 \text{ where, } a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2 \in \mathbb{R}$
\item $
  \left\{\begin{array}{cll}
    x=g(t)\\
    y=h(t)
  \end{array}\right. \text{, where }c_1<t< c_2 \text{ and } c_1,c_2 \in \mathbb{R}
  \text{.}$ \label{arraystuff}
\end{enumerate}

Use \ref{foo} to \dots or \ref{arraystuff}

\end{document}
```

[image]